# Asynchronous request-response across two Netty channels in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I have to integrate with a legacy host that uses TCP/IP communication with separate request and response channels. You send a request to the host on one channel where it is the server, and you need to have a server channel open on which it will send the response some time later. The communication is asynchronous, so there is no guarantee that the next message you receive will be the response to the request you just sent - you have to use a correlation key in the response to tie it back to the request.

I have a Camel route that takes the incoming request and sends it out to the host, and another route that listens for the responses. I have a third route that uses an aggregator to tie the response back to the request using a correlation key. Roughly speaking, the routes look like this:

```
from("direct:myService")
  .process(exchange -> exchange.setProperty("CorrelationKey", exchange.getIn().getBody(MyMessage.class).getCorrelationKey())
  .to("netty4:tcp://somehost:555")
  .to("direct:aggregate");

from("netty4:tcp://localhost:555")
  .process(exchange -> exchange.setProperty("CorrelationKey", exchange.getIn().getBody(MyResponse.class).getCorrelationKey())
  .to("direct:aggregate");

from("direct:aggregate")
  .aggregate(header("CorrelationKey"), (oldEx, newEx) -> {
    if (oldEx == null) {
      return newEx;
    }
    oldEx.getOut().setBody(newEx.getIn().getBody());
    oldEx.setProperty(Exchange.AGGREGATION_COMPLETE_CURRENT_GROUP, true)
    return oldEx;
  }).completionTimeout(5000)
  .process(exchange -> logger.log("Received response"));
```

The aggregation strategy works in the sense that I only see the log message once the response has been processed. The problem is that the request route ("direct:myService") doesn't wait for the aggregation - it has already returned back to the caller. What I want is for that route to block until the aggregation strategy has got the response, so that the message received by the netty4 consumer is used as the out message of the direct:myService route. Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you not do the aggregate in the same route as the request route and put it after the netty4 route?

Comment: Alternatively you could use camel-cache to store the correlationid's and simply do a lookup to see if it matches an existing one or not.

Comment: How would the consumer route get into the aggregate? Can you have a to() that sends to a particular node within another route? I thought you could only send to another endpoint. In the end I used a transfer queue rather than an aggregator, so that the first route is polling on a queue until the response route puts its message onto the queue. The queues are stored in a map keyed by the correlation id.

Comment: I am not sure the direct endpoint allows you to block until the entire route is finished. I doubt it but perhaps you can ask this on the Camel forum. By the way, why do you want to block and not let more messages be passed?